# Can `nan` weights occur, in PyTorch, with increase in the number of a epochs?

Tags: pytorch, nan, epoch

I am trying to run a neural network model with a *more* number of epochs (say 800) in PyTorch. I observed that the network is generating `nan` values at some epoch (say 200) and may behave normally after some epochs (say 400) or may continue with `nan` values (till 800). I am guessing that some *weights* of the neural network are becoming `nan`.

Is it true that if I increase the number of epochs, then the weights of the neural network **may** become `nan`?

Comment: You can search for the cause of the nans using [anomaly detection](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/autograd.html#anomaly-detection). The question needs more details to be answerable, but one possibility for getting nan values after a large number of epochs is exploding gradients, which can be handled by gradient clipping.

Comment: @GoodDeeds I tried for gradient clipping after the suggestion. But still happening.

Comment: @GoodDeeds I will check for anomaly detection now.